# Como enviar/receber dados do cliente para o servidor?

Tags: node.js

Como enviar/receber dados do cliente para o servidor, fazendo requisições como busca no banco dinamicamente?

Comment: Conhece o conceito de WebService e JSON? Isso vai te ajudar muito com qualquer aplicação que precise acessar dados em um BD.

Comment: Só pra esclarecer, o que você precisa é de um exemplo de como fazer uma requisição?

Comment: Sim exatamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se estiveres a usar o Express podes receber dados via app.get() ou app.post()

- app.get()

Os dados passados no GET (url por exemplo: `google.com?foo=bar&animal=gato`) vão estar disponiveis via `req.query`. Um exemplo seria:

```
app.get('/pasta', function(req, res){
    var foo = req.query.foo;
    // etc
});
```

- app.post()

Os dados passados no POST estão disponíveis via `req.body`. Ou seja se tiveres uma `<form action="/pasta" ...` e um input: `<input type="text" name="animal" />` esses dados podem ser usados assim:

```
app.post('/pasta', function(req, res){
    var animal= req.body.animal;
    // etc
});
```

Comment: Ok, mais como faço para enviar do cliente para o servidor isso? ex: tenho um form no arquivo 'index.htm' e  quero enviar os dados para o express app.js, como seria na pagina html isso?

Comment: @RafaelVergoPolan como coloquei na resposta tem de indicar o caminho (path) na propriedade da form (`<form action="/pasta" ...`) Aí o Express vai buscar os dados da form usando a propriedade `name=""` de cada input. Só tem de ter um botão ou input com `type="submit"` para a form ser enviada.

Comment: entendi, essa pagina que contem o form tem que ser gerada pelo express ou pode ser qualquer?

Comment: @RafaelVergoPolan se percebi bem a sua poergunta pode ser qualquer. O importante é que `app.post('/endereco', function(req, res){` tenha o mesmo endereço que o action da form.

Answer (score 2):

Querido tenha em mente que tudo no computador é programatico, você tem que criar seu padrão ou pesquisar padrões pois a comunidade já tem feito muitos padrões como você também já quis fazer tudo dinamico porém a realidade é outra, quando o conhecimento é pouco aprendemos divagarzinho,então use o seu padrão ou o padrão estudado tanto no front-end como no back-end, dinamicamente é complicado, e é difícil você fazer algo, porém se você quer enviar dados pelo front-end e receber no back-end com codigo puro, segue código abaixo.

espero ter ajudado com o código abaixo.

FRONT-END USO VUE.JS

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="dado"><button v-on:click="enviar">click</button>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  from axios import 'axios'

  export default {
    name: 'dadosenviados',
    data: function () {
      return {
        dado: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      enviar: function () {
        var this_ = this
        axios({
          url: "seu_ip_do_Back_end/rota", method: "POST", { data: this_.dado }
       })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

BACK-END uso puro NODE.js

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  // quiser ver o url
  console.log(request.url);

  // quiser ver o method
  console.log(request.method);

  // pegando o dado.
  // assim você faz o download do dado.

  var body = '';
  request.on('data', function (data) {
    body += data;
  })

  // quando terminar o download
  request.on('end', function () {

    // formato que vio é uma string.
    console.log(body);
    console.log(typeof(body));

    // caso queira o obj
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    console.log(typeof(JSON.parse(body)));
  })

})

server.listen('127.0.0.1', '8181', function () {
  console.log('Server open in http://127.0.0.1:8181/');
});
```

Caso queira banco de dados, baixe o MySql e salve no seu projeto.

comando:

```
$ npm install mysql
```

agora crie uma conexão

```
const mysql_con = require('mysql');

const sql = mysql_con.createConnection({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '3306',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'teste'
})
```

CASO QUERI MAIS aconselho A ler a documentação.